# Why class attribute cannot assign inline by javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>     
      .tagging {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 20px;
        height: 30px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        div[0].class = "tagging";
      }     
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I wonder why it doesn't work when I assign class attribute via javascript, but it works when I assign inline directly in html

```
<div class="tagging"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className

Comment: Sine `class` is a reserved keyword in many languages, the creators of the DOM API decided to map the `class` attribute to the `className` property. In JavaScript it wouldn't actually matter because even though `class` *is* a reserved keyword, you can use such keywords as property names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `className`.

Try:

```
div[0].className = "tagging";
```

If you want to add tha class to the existing one you can use:

```
div[0].className += " tagging"; // adding white-space is important
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e2BSp/)**

**To read:** MDN [**className**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className).

Answer (score 4):

use `className`, so change:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
div[0].class = "tagging";
```

to

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
div[0].className = "tagging";
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6yfH/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1" class="someclass">
    <img ... id="image1" name="image1" />
</div>
```

Then:

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className = d.className + " otherclass";
```